# Scatterplot grouped by a column

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a scatterplot over two different types of categorical variables, each with three different levels. Right now I am using the seaborn library in python:

```py
sns.pairplot(x_vars = ['UTM_x'], y_vars = ['UTM_y'], data = df, hue = "Mobility_Provider", height = 5)
sns.pairplot(x_vars = ['UTM_x'], y_vars = ['UTM_y'], data = df, hue = "zone_number", height = 5)
```

which gives me two separate scatter plot, one grouped by Mobility_Provider, one grouped by zone_number. However, I was wondering if it's possible to combine these two graphs together, e.g. different levels of Mobility_Provider are represented in different colours, while different levels of zone_number are represented in different shapes/markers of the plot.
Thanks a lot!

A sample plot would be:
[Plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFv3x.png)
[Plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYcP6.png)

Each row of the df has x and y values, and two categorical variables ("Mobility_Provider" and "zone_number")

Comment: can you please provide a sample `df` and the current plots

Comment: Hi I've added the plots and description of my dataframe

Comment: The x and y coordinates are same, so the plots will perfectly overlap, are you sure you need that. Take a look at the images, if you plot them together you will only see the last one

Comment: I think you misunderstood my idea, say if point (200, 100) has Mobility_Provider:1 and zone_number:1, then it should be a red circle. Same, if point (200, 100) has Mobility_Provider:1 and zone_number:2, then it should be a red triangle; if point (200, 100) has Mobility_Provider:2 and zone_number:1, then it should be a blue circle.

Comment: since there's two categorical variables, each with three possible values, I want it to be something like combinations of {red, blue, yellow} x {circle, triangle, rectangle}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done using seaborn's scatterplot, just use
`hue = "Mobility_Provider",style="zone_number"`
Something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4],'y':[1,2,3,4],'Mobility_Provider':[0,0,1,1],\
                   'zone_number':[0,1,0,1]})

sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y",s=100,hue='Mobility_Provider',style='zone_number', data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image]